# What is app in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Hi i am creating visualforce pages and apex classes triggers etc for last some  time.i want to know what is app in salesforce and how to publish it on AppExchange? Any requirement for publishing app on app exchange i went through this tutorial [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVITwMCotP8)

they teach how to create an app in developer org by default there are 6 tabs Home,Chatter,File,Your Tab ,Reports,DashBoard.i basically want to know what app contains? apex class,visualforce page these components or only standard tabs and some customization tab what we see when we select an app in developer org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `app` in Salesforce.com is nothing but a container which contains in it - a name, a logo, and an ordered set of tabs.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/Content/adg_simple_app_introduction.htm

All the metadata such as `Objects`, `Visualforce Pages`, `Classes`, etc are independent of an `app`. An `app` just helps to group things together **visually**. But internally the metadata has nothing to do with an `app` i.e. you can have the same `tab`, `VF Page` in multiple apps.

Publishing an app on AppExchange is a long procedure. Please follow the AppExchange Publishing Guide https://sites.secure.force.com/appexchange/resource/1237050882000/help/index_Left.htm for full details on how to publish your app on AppExchange.

Comment: thanks but u didnt tell about how to publish an app in app exchange.please reply after that i will mark it answer.thanks again

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta Updated the post - added link to `AppExchange Publishing Guide`. You may also refer [Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In salesforce there are two types of apps:

1. Standard
2. Custom

Custom app is a collection of custom objects and standard objects (not neccessary all time) which are accessible through tabs which is shown on the top of the ui where objects are like collection of records. Records are just the collection of fields and fields are basically the smallest entities.

So all these things fall under apps in sf.